# AttributeError: module 'environ' has no attribute 'Env'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a django app. And I try to use the module environ.

Of course I googled a lot on this error. But I can't figure out what is wrong whith the setup.

So this is part of my settings.py file:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import environ


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))

SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = env('DEBUG')

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": env.db(),
}
```

and .env file looks like:

```
DEBUG=on
```

but for exmaple when I try to run the app with:

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.135:8000
```

I get this error:

```
File "C:\repos\DWL_backend\zijn\settings.py", line 19, in <module>
    env = environ.Env()
AttributeError: module 'environ' has no attribute 'Env'
```

and I installed already the module

```
django-environ = "*"
```

Question: how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably installed the wrong module. My IDE suggested `pip install environ`, which is a [different package](https://pypi.org/project/environ/) and a wrong suggestion. The one you need to install here is `pip install django-environ`. Run `pip freeze` and make sure you have the `django-environ`, not the other one.

Comment: You still seem to pull in a wrong package somehow. Inside the code, you can try to see what packages you are using by printing them via something like `print([sys.modules[name] for name in set(sys.modules) & set(globals())])`. Mine lists `python3.11/site-packages/environ/__init__.py`, you can open that file and at the top it should say it belongs to `django-environ`. If it points you to a different package, pip uninstall it. The other two packages you mentioned seem unrelated to this.